What is the geometrical interpretation/intuition behind complex eigenvectors and eigenvalues?
As far as I know, matrices are transformations of the x-y coordinate systems i.e. the rotations and skews.
As for eigenvectors, they are the vectors, which after transformation, remain oriented the same in direction but get scaled by some lambda (which is its corresponding eigenvalue).
Now, what if I rotated the coordinate system by 90 degrees. Which means by i vector (the x unit vector) lands on (0,1) and the j vector (the y unit vector) lands on (-1,0).
The eigenvalues that this matrix dishes out are +- iota.
My question being, what does being "scaled" by iota even mean? And on such rotation , how can any vector have the same directional orientation?

Multiplication by $i$ corresponds to $90^\circ$ rotation

Notice that if $Av = iv$, then $A^2v = -v$, so $A$ does "half" of a $180^\circ$ rotation to $v$, which is a $90^\circ$ rotation.

no, i understand the rotation part. but what I'm trying to get a hold on about what a complex eigenvector means. So what my best guess was is that maybe since we are rotating the xy plane itself, the only possible eigenvector that could exist is the z axis. But since it doesn't exist for a 2D space, we're getting a complex value?

Ahh i see, thanks!

$2$-dimensional complex vectors correspond to $4$-dimensional real vectors, so they’re hard to visualize, right?

If you have a real matrix with complex eigenvalue $a+ib$ and complex eigenvector $x+iy$, then the real subspace generated by $x,y$ is invariant with respect to the matrix, and when restricted to that subspace, the transformation acts like $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$ which is essentially scaling by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and rotating by $-\tan^{-1}(b/a)$.
